# aggregation project mongodb output not expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm coding a complex query in javascript.
and I'm using aggregation.
I'm using two tables. invoice, travel

this is my code.

```
      Invoice.aggregate([
        // filter the documents from invoice of only 2016
        {
          $match: {
            executed: {
              $gte: startDate,
              $lte: endDate
            },
            "modelHolder.name": 'Travel'
          }
        },

        // $lookup is working alone, it is not taking the input from function 1 of aggregate
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "travels",
            localField: "modelHolder.id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "dataFromTravels"
          }
        },

        // filter by date of reservation and date of arrival
          $match: { $or:
  [
    {
      'dataFromTravels.from.date': {
        $gte: departDate, $lte: endDate
      }
    },
    {
      'dataFromTravels.to.date': {
        $lte: arrivalDate
      },
    }
  ]
      }
    },


        {
          $limit: 2
        }
        // 2nd function to work on the first function output as the input
      ], function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          return console.log(('ERROR', err));
          //next(err);
        } else {
          console.log('Result', result);
         // res.json(result);
          return;
        }
      });

      // console.log('invoice  !');
      // console.log(invoice._id);
      self.resume();
    })

    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.error('Error occurred while streaming invoices', err);
    })

    .on('end', function () {
      console.log('Successfully displayed invoices');
      cb();
    });
```

I want to have the list of cars and count how many times we used each of them in the period restricted in the match functions.

I added this.

```
    {
$group: { "_id": "$dataFromTravels.car.plateNumber", "count": { $sum: 1 } }
            },
```

the car is under travel table.
and I just got an array of 3 cars. or I have hundreds of cars in the same period.

How could I manage this?

thanks for you suggestions.

Comment: Can you add the input parameter values along with sample doc from both the collections and expected json response to the post ?

Comment: how bro? I did not understand your point

Comment: I mean can you add some sample docs from `invoice` and `travel `collection  and along with expected response from the above query

Comment: can you please write an exemple for me?

Comment: I mean tables `invoice` and `travel`. Can you see the data in those tables ? Can you copy some data to the post ? So people can run the your query against the data.

Comment: done =D take a look please

Comment: What values of `startDate` and `endDate` do you pass for the matching function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make a join query using mongodb. The target collection is stored as an array. so when you make use of lookup

```
{
    $lookup: {
      from: "travels",
      localField: "modelHolder.id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "dataFromTravels"
   }
}
```

The output of the query will be like:-

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("554dc5e937c1482c491d9d36"),
  // invoice data
  "dataFromTravels": [
    // travel data
  ]
}
```

And with mongodb aggregation you cannot use $match over nested documents.
So, in the query to match

```
db.invoice.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      executed: {
        $gte: ISODate(startDate),
        $lte: ISODate(endDate)
      },
      "modelHolder.name": 'Travel'
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "travels",
      localField: "modelHolder.id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "dataFromTravels"
    }
  }, {
    $unwind: "$dataFromTravels"
  },{
  $match: {
    $or: [{
      'dataFromTravels.from.date': {
        $gte: ISODate(startDate),
        $lte: ISODate(endDate)
      }
    }, {
      'dataFromTravels.to.date': {
        $lte: ISODate(startDate)
      },
    }]
  }
  }, {
    $limit: 2
  }
]);
```

Now, the dataFromTravels will be available as an object & you can use $match over the **from** & **to** properties